# Angular2 code coverage options

Tags: javascript, angular, code-coverage

Javascript has following code coverage options like: Istanbul, Karma, Blanket.js, and JSCover.But what about these tools support in Angular2 ?
We know Istanbul is possible with Angular2 ,but what about other coverage tools.

Comment: I refereed this question and answer is clear from that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108640/webpack-karma-istanbul-remapping-for-typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular CLI creates projects with Istanbul built-in. You run `ng test --code-coverage` to get the `lcov` file generated, and you get access to the karma config in your project to customize the integration as needed.

For example, in my project, in the file `karma.conf.js`, I have things like:

```
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: '../reports/jsCoverage',
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    ...
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
```

### Update:

In the recent versions of Angular CLI (not sure since when, but sure in v 1.2+, maybe even 1.1), your karma config doesn't even have the `reporter` part above. The CLI adds `coverage-istanbul` by itself as needed.

Comment: The correct command in the current version is ng test --code-coverage, not ng test --coverage

Answer (score 0):

This link clearly explains typescript based Code coverage :-https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/09/29/code-coverage-for-typescript-and-other-transpiled-languages/